# Is it possible to reduce the number of spaces to only one between words?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to reduce the number of spaces to only one one between words?

For example:

```
"My  name  Ruby" => "My name Ruby"
"this is  a good   boy" => "this is a good boy"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`squeeze`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-squeeze):

```
"now   is  the".squeeze(" ") #=> "now is the"
```

Comment: Wooww!! Ruby has everything. I overlooked this one from the doc. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
content.gsub(/\s+/, " ").strip
```

gsub returns a copy of the content string with all occurrences of the regex pattern substituted with the second argument (" "). \s stands for "whitespace character". + means one or more.

Comment: Could you please explain it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` and `join` :

Your string:

```
string = "   My      name           is      Ruby          "
```

command:

```
 p string.split(" ").join(" ")
```

output:

```
"My name is Ruby"
```

Comment: Strictly speaking this doesn't give the desired result, which should be `" My name is Ruby "`. Good answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Mischa I do not see any blank space requirement (in the beginning and end of string) in his question.Therefore this solution counts with this output: `"My name is Ruby"`

Comment: The only requirement in the question is to remove double spaces (between words). Your solution also removes spaces (even single spaces) from the beginning of the string. The only reason I made this remark is your own example, which has spaces at the beginning and end of the string. I think your answer is good and I upvoted it, but *strictly* speaking it does not give the desired result.

Comment: @Mischa I want learn from this example as well. Therefore just wanted to ask for more details. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `gsub`:

```
yourstring.gsub!(/\s\s+/,' ')
```

Comment: Or `gsub(/\s{2,}/, ' ')`. However, `\s` isn't "space", it's white-space, which contains a number of other characters. `/\s/ - A whitespace character: /[ \t\r\n\f]/`